# CSS - affect <hr> element with hovering over <p> element

Tags: html, css, hover

```css
.about:hover > .left {
  color: #DAFDBA;
}
```

```html
HTML: >
<div class="navbar">
  <!--Lines above Links-->

  <hr class="left">
  <hr class="middle">
  <hr class="right">

  <!--Links (Text)-->
  <p class="about"><a href="about">About.</a></p>
  <p class="projects"><a href="projects">Projects.</a></p>
  <p class="contact"><a href="contact">Contact.</a></p>

</div>
```

What should be the statement between `.about:hover` and `.left?`

Comment: `>` selector is to select the direct child of an element. `.left` is not a direct child of `.about` also `.about:hover` will mostlikely not work. `.about a:hover` will work. however this makes it impossible to select the `<hr>`

Comment: hi @jan_lampert, basically you can't do what you want in plain css.
You can't affect an element hovering something other than that element or its ancestors.

Comment: @salvo Could I just change their positions?

Comment: @jan_lampert you have to use some javascript, You want me to provide a jQuery solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code like this if you just want to have three links with one line above each one, and hovering over the link the line turns green

```css
a{
  color:inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  padding:.2em 0 0;
  margin: 0 .2em;
}
a:hover {
  border-color: #DAFDBA;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="about">About</a> 
  <a href="projects">Projects</a> 
  <a href="contact">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Just to improve the semantics: instead of `<div class="navbar>"` the semantic tag `<nav>` should be used.